# Locking and blocking lifetime on UNION queries on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking, union

Can anyone shed any light on how locking works on `UNION` queries? Say I have the below query and the Archive tables take 1 min to run while the non-archive tables take 5s. Are any locks taken on the non-archive tables held until the whole query executes?

```
SELECT
    COH.OrderNumber,
    COH.OrderType,
    COH.OrderDate,
    COL.Product,
    COH.Customer,
    SUM(COL.Quantity) Quantity,
    SUM(COL.Quantity* COL.Price) Ext
FROM

    CustomerOrderHeaders COH

    JOIN CustomerOrderLines COL ON COH.OrderNumber = COL.OrderNumber
GROUP BY

    COH.OrderNumber,
    COH.OrderType,
    COH.OrderDate,
    COL.Product,
    COH.Customer
UNION
ALL
SELECT

    COH.OrderNumber,
    COH.OrderType,
    COH.OrderDate,
    COL.Product,
    COH.Customer,
    SUM(COL.Quantity) Quantity,
    SUM(COL.Quantity * COL.Price) Ext
FROM

    CustomerOrderHeadersArchive COH

    JOIN CustomerOrderLinesArchive COL ON COH.OrderNumber = COL.OrderNumber
GROUP BY

    COH.OrderNumber,
    COH.OrderType,
    COH.OrderDate,
    COL.Product,
    COH.Customer
```

Comment: You should ask a different question.  For performance problems/questions, I suggest you first ask "what are the query plans?" and that might give you insight.  Contention via locks could be a problem, but not all query operations take time because of locks.  SSMS has a feature to let you see "live" query plans where it will show you the hot query operators, so I suggest you start there.

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT thanks, I'm not too concerned about the performance of this query as such. But if it holds locks on the non-archive tables for as long as the archive tables take to complete, then it will be blocking other queries causing performance issues in other areas.

Comment: @TheRealTy were you able to understand how locking works?

Answer (score 1):

Locks are taken to preserve transaction isolation as described on the [Transaction Basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#Basics) doc. If the release of the lock doesn't hurt the ACID properties, there's no reason for SQL Server to keep a resource locked and, in fact, the sooner the lock is released the better for good performance.

If you see the [Lock Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#lock_modes), you'll find that the query from your question is most likely taking [Shared Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#shared):

> Shared (S) locks allow concurrent transactions to read (SELECT) a
> resource under pessimistic concurrency control. No other transactions
> can modify the data while shared (S) locks exist on the resource.
> **Shared (S) locks on a resource are released as soon as the read
> operation completes**, unless the transaction isolation level is set to
> repeatable read or higher, or a locking hint is used to retain the
> shared (S) locks for the duration of the transaction. [emphasis added]

So no, the fact that your second query takes longer to run doesn't mean it causes the tables on the first one to be held util the end of the whole `UNION`. Microsoft has a doc on [How to: Determine Which Queries Are Holding Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb677357(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) that uses Extended Events to exhibit the locks (acquired and released). I used the proposed session on a AdventureWorks2016 database to check the following query:

```
SELECT ShoppingCartID, ModifiedDate
FROM Sales.ShoppingCartItem

UNION

SELECT SalesOrderDetailID, ModifiedDate 
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
```

[image: Live data]

That query is similar to yours and you'll be able to see locks being acquired and released interchangeably, instead of only acquired at the beginning and released at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, sql releases the lock when it does not need the resource anymore, i.e after commit. It follows the Two-Phase Locking.

I would recommend trying to start your union query and then start an update on the non-archive table to see if the update goes after 5 seconds or after 1 minute.